# Azure Logic Apps - Need to get Status Code from Output on Do Until Condition

Tags: workflow

I have received this statusCode error when my logic app.  I would like to be able to retrieve the statusCode to use in a do until loop to check if the statusCode is 200, otherwise continue to loop until it find the condition I am looking for.

This is my output.

{
"statusCode": 404,
"headers": {
"Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
"Vary": "Accept-Encoding",
"Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000",
"request-id": "9808d380-51ee-460a-b3f3-7a31c8137908",
"client-request-id": "9808d380-51ee-460a-b3f3-7a31c8137908",
"x-ms-ags-diagnostic": "{"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"East US 2","Slice":"E","Ring":"5","ScaleUnit":"000","RoleInstance":"BN5PEPF0000E14F"}}",
"Timing-Allow-Origin": "*",
"x-ms-apihub-cached-response": "true",
"x-ms-apihub-obo": "false",
"Date": "Thu, 28 Sep 2023 21:38:25 GMT",
"Content-Type": "application/json"
},
"body": {
"error": {
"code": "NotFound",
"message": "GetOperation : Operation id not found for given Team. GroupId:d53106a9-3347-4d09-8c3f-86a09da0bbc3 OperationId:50f32ed4-7a8f-43da-b8c4-74f8bd14fb25",
"innerError": {
"message": "GetOperation : Operation id not found for given Team. GroupId:d53106a9-3347-4d09-8c3f-86a09da0bbc3 OperationId:50f32ed4-7a8f-43da-b8c4-74f8bd14fb25",
"code": "ItemNotFound",
"innerError": {},
"date": "2023-09-28T21:38:26",
"request-id": "9808d380-51ee-460a-b3f3-7a31c8137908",
"client-request-id": "9808d380-51ee-460a-b3f3-7a31c8137908"
}
}
}
}

[image]

I've initialized a variable as an integer and set a variable to update in the do loop at:

int(outputs('Name_of_Task')['statusCode'])

However, I am not sure this is correct.  Also my title has spaces.  Do I have to use underscores when referencing it?